# Why does apt-get install also upgrade unrelated packages?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-10.10

I entered apt-get install sysstat, and not only was sysstat installed, but it also upgraded my version of Hbase.

Am I missing something basic here, shouldn't apt-get install only install or upgrade related packages?

This happened on Ubuntu Maverick.

Comment: I have to ask because it's so close--did it upgrade hbase or lsb-base?  Did you have hbase installed on there before, as I don't find it in the standard repositories?

Comment: have you tried [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)?

Comment: @Theo hbase - I have it pointing to a third party source.

Comment: @mbx - didn't know it existed, thanks, though it's not immediately clear to me if it's better to post Ubuntu related sysops questions here or there.

Comment: In such a case I would have tried it there first, as there are possibly more users with problems like that and you'll get propably more answers. On the other hand, this may affect also other debian like distros, so asking it here is wise too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `apt-get install` will only upgrade packages that are a dependency, directly or indirectly of the requested packages.  Try installing `apt-rdepends` and run `apt-rdepends sysstat | grep -i hbase`.  If I'm right, you should see the hbase packages in there somewhere.

Comment: It's not, I was able to install it on an identical machine w/out the incidental upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that packages that are pending an upgrade will be listed as such when you do anything at all with apt-get; but they are not necessarily installed or upgraded.

Are you sure that it did in fact upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I can't reproduce the behavior on other machines, though.